# Multi-tenant dynamic multiple domains with SSL pointing to single Host/CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, devops, sni

I am building a multi-tenant social network platform of sorts. Something like you'd see at a squarespace or shopify where you as a customer can map your custom domain name eg, community.mywebsite.com to the hosted platform eg, app.socialnetwork.com

I'm sure some reverse proxy magic would need to be involved. And some kind of component for free automatic SSL creation.

I imagine whatever solution should be able to handle thousands of mapped domain names all pointing to the single location.

Currently the web app can be hosted as a static site, so i've had success with AWS CloudFront etc, but they have limits (10) on the number of domains and its a very manual process, although i did find some APIs. Just unsure if this is an acceptable use of their platform.

I can see here these folks share similar issues:
[Multi-tenant application on CloudBees with multiple SSL certificates (SNI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708273/multi-tenant-application-on-cloudbees-with-multiple-ssl-certificates-sni)
and
[Using public SSL for dynamic domains to map on single cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790214/using-public-ssl-for-dynamic-domains-to-map-on-single-cloudfront#comment102251210_57790214)

This fellow also seems curious about the same thing https://serverfault.com/questions/976582/how-does-shopify-manage-hundreds-of-thousands-domains-to-one-ip

I've come across traefik.io which may be what i'm after, but then theres set up.

So i'm fairly certain what i need is:

- map customer's domains to our stuff
- generate free ssl cert
- apply cert and route domain. This nodejs code looks like it would serve that using SNI and the https createServer SNICallback however i'm unsure just how many domains that could handle, suppose its dependant on how performant the callback code is when say requesting from a database the list of domains and certs https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1118#issuecomment-269085503

Appreciate any info, pointers in the right direction and naturally if theres an all in one service that does it all i'll consider throwing money at the problem :)

Comment: I get the feeling the SSL Custom Hostnames enterprise feature might be what i'm after. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217371987-Managing-Custom-Hostnames-SSL-for-SaaS-

Comment: Hey Steve, did you ever make any progress on this? Did you end up using the CloudFlare SSL for SaaS?

Comment: @StevePascoe would be interested to know if you found some good info on this too..